# How to secure client http calls to the backend?

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, websecurity

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to prevent random people access/make requests to the server.
Currently, everyone that have the url and the endpoint can easily make requests and I believe it's kind of security breach.

I am using Express.js that hosting static build of React.js

Here is an example of a call:

// Client:

```
async function getData(id){
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`${backendDomain}/data/${id}`)
    const data = res.data
  
    return data
  } catch (error) {
    ...
  }
}
```

// Server:

```
app.get('/data/:id', function(req, res) {
  ...logic
  res.send(data);
});
```

I tried adding to the Client "x-api-key" header and pass an api key that only I have and add a middleware that will check the api and see if it passed currectly from the client. But obviously it is not a good solution because you can see the key on "Network" section while inspecting.

What can I do?

Looking for the best way to prevent random people accessing the data

Comment: The client needs to know the `x-api-key` anyway, so you need not worry that it shows up on the "Network" tab. What matters is if someone _between_ client and server can see it, and that is prevented by the use of HTTPS.

Comment: When hosting a server on https cloud service, isn't that considered as https?

Comment: Yes, that is https.

Comment: I am not sure what your meaning. when I'm trying to make a simple postman request with the production url + endpoint of the server, which is https (for example heroku hosting). if I have the api key it will go through. The api is visible on the "Network" tab so it can be easily done by anyone.

Comment: @RoyBenAviv, you can see that key in the Network tab of devtools? Then your primary problem is to protect your pc from unauthorized access and host your apps on a server where only you can access. https takes care of all other things.

Comment: @pierpy So if I understand, if I make a call to a private server the api key will not be visible on the dev tools?
It should be like: front -> private server -> server of the app?

Comment: No @RoyBenAviv, you can always see that in devtools

Comment: @pierpy thank you for your answer, but to be completly honest I still have no idea how to implement a security method. Not sure what action should I do in order to avoid people making calls to my backend